# Extract Int from regex using pattern matching without extracting as String and then casting toInt

Tags: regex, scala, pattern-matching

I have a year, expressed in the format `XXYY-ZZ`. For example, the year `2020-21` would represent a year spanning 2020 to 2021. I need to extract `XXYY`, `YY` and `ZZ` as Ints to use in calculations later.

Using Pattern matching and regex, I can extract values I want as Strings, like this:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex
val YearFormatRegex: Regex = "(20([1-9][0-9]))-([1-9][0-9])".r

"2020-21" match {
  case YearFormatRegex(fullStartYear, start, end) => println(fullStartYear, start, end)
  case _                                          => println("did not match")
}
// will print (2020, 20, 21)
```

However I need the values as Ints. Is there a way to extract these values as Ints without  throwing `.toInt` all over the place? I understand that the regex specifically looks for numbers so extracting them as Strings and *then* parsing as Ints seems like an unnecessary step if I can avoid it.

Comment: Regex is only operating on strings. You need to cast the extracted strings to int sooner or later if you need that type of data.

Comment: @Wiktor I understand that, I suppose I was hoping that there would be a convenient way to cast it to Int as it was matching, since I can already extract the values using the above method and in order to match in the first place they need to be numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply encapsulate the conversion, one way to do it could be to create your own extractor object built around your regular expression, e.g.:

```
import scala.util.matching.Regex

object Year {
  
  private val regex: Regex = "(20([1-9][0-9]))-([1-9][0-9])".r
  
  def unapply(s: String): Option[(Int, Int, Int)] =
    s match {
      case regex(prefix, from, to) => Some((prefix.toInt, from.toInt, to.toInt))
      case _ => None
    }
  
  
}

"2020-21" match {
  case Year(fullStartYear, start, end) => fullStartYear - start + end
  case _ => 0
} // returns 2020 - 20 + 21 = 2021
```

You can read more on extractor objects [here on the Scala official documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/extractor-objects.html).

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/sZ4kbyWcRcWRNNw5BvZ3Cw/37).